# deploy shinyapp with python into shinyapps.io

Tags: python, py-shiny

I'm trying to deploy a shiny app using Python into Shinyapps.io but when I run the deploy,

```
rsconnect deploy shiny first_python_app --name myaccount --title first_python_app_test
```

I get,

```
Validating server...    [OK]
Validating app mode...  [OK]
Making bundle ...       [OK]
Deploying bundle ...
Waiting for task: 1328066592
  building - Installing packages
  building - Installing packages
  building - Installing packages
  .
  .
  .
  building - Installing packages
  building - Installing packages
[ERROR] 2023-08-18T09:45:38-0500 Build logs:
Quarto not found.
        [ERROR]: Application deployment failed with error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 1328066593 error: Unhandled Exception: 599
Error: Application deployment failed with error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 1328066593 error: Unhandled Exception: 599
```

I tried to reinstall the quarto extension in VScode but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. After the error, I tried to make a new original shiny app using shiny create and directly deployed that file. It worked, I tried to deploy it again on the previous app and the error is gone. If you already solved the problem and found the culprit please update it here.